# Excel VBA - Display next cell if previous cell includes text

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a Genius in Excel VBA, so here is my question:

I have an Excel Sheet which has hidden rows.

For example: As long as cell A1 is empty keep the row(A2) hidden. When A1 includes text show the next row (A2).

My Approach was the following:

```
    Sub showRows_Klicken()

    Dim rng As Range

        For Each rng In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp))       
              If LCase(rng) = "text"    
                  Then                                            
                        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
              Else

              End If
        Next rng

     End Sub
```

I hope somebody can help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code. Worked for me. Please give it a try

```
Sub Macro1()

    If Range("A1").Value = vbNullString Then
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) Then
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked for hidding the column, I will need to hide the row.

Comment: Just replace "Columns" with "Row" in the code and replace B:B with row number (eg: 2:2,)

Answer (score 0):

The `Hidden` property seems to work. I've changed the function a bit such that it sets the next row (*i+1*) visible based on row *i*. It now only checks each 2nd row, otherwise you could hide all rows (if there were nothing), and you would not be able to set any "text" such that the next row is unhidden:

```
Sub showRows_Klicken()
'loop all rows
For i = 1 To 65536 Step 2
    'check if has string "text" and set hidden
    If LCase(Cells(i, 1)) = "text" Then
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, I had an endless loop with your code. Problem is solved, though. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it has an endless loop, for me it simply takes a long time since it is done for 65536/2 rows.

Comment: After I have clicked the button, it took a minute and crashed my application. I had to restart the whole thing. Could be an issue with my Excel version. (2010)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I changed the code a bit and now it works for me:

```
         Sub Schaltfläche259_Klicken()
            If Range("A1").Value = vbNullString Then
                Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) Then
                Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If

         End Sub
```